# Passing macro arguments to function with comma

Tags: c

In the MSP430 world, the driverlib has functions for working with GPIO pins:

```
GPIO_SetAsInputPin(port, pin)
```

I would like a single macro to define a single pin, for example:

```
#define PB1     (GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN4)
#define PB2     (GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN5)
```

When I call the function with the macro:

```
GPIO_setAsInputPin(PB1);
```

I get a too few arguments in function call error.  Is there a different way of making this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses around the expansion of PB1 make it into a single argument with a comma operator in between — so your invocation expands to:

```
GPIO_setAsInputPin((GPIO_PORT_P2, GPIO_PIN4))
```

You should probably use:

```
#define PB1   (GPIO_PORT_P2), (GPIO_PIN4)
```

which expands to:

```
GPIO_setAsInputPin((GPIO_PORT_P2), (GPIO_PIN4))
```

giving you two arguments.  Or you could omit the parentheses around the names and you'd probably be safe.

You may still have problems if `GPIO_setAsInputPin` is itself a macro that expects two arguments.  Then you'd need something like:

```
#define GPIO_setAsInputPin_1(x)    GPIO_setAsInputPin(x)
```

and you would invoke:

```
GPIO_setAsInputPin_1(PB1);
```

and you'd get as output:

```
GPIO_setAsInputPin((GPIO_PORT_P2), (GPIO_PIN4));
```

or whatever the underlying macro expands to.